# Override BCC in TYPO3 power mail for a particular form

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

I have been using different Kontakt forms in my TYPO3 9 LTS, I wanted to set bcc for a particular form. How can Set that? If I use
'plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc.value = abc@gmail.com'
It will override all form's BCC. Is there any way to set bcc for a particular form with form Id?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

there is no concept in TYPO3 for setting typoscript values for individual records, except for pages context.

If you know the pages your special form is used you can use conditions to set special values. That would enable a centralized typoscript.
Another way would be to have extension templates (records) in those pages which set 'local' typoscript.

This kind of information does not belong in typoscript (which represents global configuration) but in the (form)records which are evaluated individually.

---

after invention of the `if`-function of `stdWrap` you could try to build a condition on special record data, but this does not work in general as it must be explicit evaluated by the extension in the record context.

something like: (but I doubt that this will work with powermail)

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc {
   value = anyone@example.com
   // any field where you can identify your form:
   if.equals.field = uid 
   // value of that field:
   if.value = 123
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but its not working.
``plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.bcc {
   value =  abc@gmail.com
   // any field where you can identify your form:
   if.equals.field = uid 
   // 5 is the value of the form uid:
   if.value = 5
}``

Comment: as expected: either the fields of 'current' record are not available in TS, or the plugin does not evaluate stdWrap functions in TS at all.